# Does Python have a convention for declaring methods as accessible from outside the class but not from outside the program?

Tags: python

Like many languages, Python has conventions for declaring methods as private, protected or public. C# additionally has "internal" methods, which are accessible from outside the class but not from outside the program.

Private and protected methods in Python aren't enforced—they're only a naming convention. Does Python have a similar convention for declaring that a method should be accessible from outside the class but not a part of the public interface? Are public methods in Python assumed to be a part of the public interface?

Comment: What would be considered "outside the program"?

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm referring to code that can only be accessed by other modules in the program.

Answer (score 2):

Could module level private functions help perhaps?

> `f.py`

```
def __privFunc():
    print 'Yes'

def func():
    print 'Yolo'
```

`__privFunc` is not imported by default

```
>>> from f import *
>>> __privFunc()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__privFunc' is not defined
>>> func()
Yolo
```